# ! Missing number, treated as zero. problem

Tags: errors

I just want to have the following simple equation. But the latex told me "! Missing number, treated as zero. problem" I have no idea what's going on here

```
\[L\mathaccent N(\mu ,{\sigma ^2})\]
```

Error message:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
to be read again,
N
l.245 \[L\mathaccent N
(\mu ,{\sigma ^2})\]
```

Kind Regards
SL

Comment: TeX expects a number after `\mathaccent`. What is the purpose of `\mathaccent` in your formula?

Comment: @David Carlisle \mathaccent is "~" in my formula, firstly I typed "~" but latex suggest me to use \mathaccent

Comment: You probably typed `\~` in order to get a tilde; if you want a tilde over `N`, then the correct command is `\tilde{N}`; if you want a tilde between `L` and `N`, then use `\sim`.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you just want ~ in your mathematical expression. But as it is interpreted by LaTeX to set an unbreakable space, you must type something like this :

```
\[L \sim N(\mu ,{\sigma ^2})\]
```